# Why do a random number of these JSONP requests fail?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

I have a jQuery `each` loop that runs through a list of three `JSONP` urls, but, a random number of them just fail with the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object [object Window] is not a function`.

It is usually one or two and sometimes none but it is never all of them, I think that it has to do with the asynchronous part but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
var feeds = ["JSONPUrl", "JSONPUrl", "JSONPUrl"];

$.each(feeds, function(index, feedUrl) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: feedUrl,
    processData : true,
    data: {
        tagmode: "any",
        jsonp: "callback",
        callback: "callback"
    },
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        // Do some DOM manipulations with the data
    },
    error: function(x,y,z) {
    }
});
});​
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to show some code I guess

Comment: You need to include the code that is doing the ajax request so we can help you. You mention a jQuery `each` loop... include that loop in your post.

Comment: Woops, thought I posted that...

Comment: OK, added sample code. But, that does not include my HTML or the JSONP urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL looks like `?callback=callback`, because of the hard-coded `callback` property. Remove this, jQuery will automatically define temporary functions with random names for the JSONP callback.

```
data: {
    tagmode: "any",
    jsonp: "callback",     // <-- Do not forget to remove the trailing comma
    callback: "callback"   // <-- Remove this!
},
jsonpCallback: "callback", // <-- Remove this!
```

If you really want to execute a function called `callback` on success, include this in the `success` handler.

Regarding the comments: If your server expects the JSONP callback parameter to be called "jsonp" instead of "callback", use:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    jsonp: "jsonp"
    ...
});
// results in http://..../?jsonp=jQuery234254342random2342etc
```

Comment: Still doing it, but, the callback is defined by `jsonp` not callback.

Comment: Now I get: jsonp is not defined

Comment: @A.M.K If I understood your first comment, the server expects `?jsonp=<callbackname>`. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Remove `jsonp: "callback"` from data, and add it to the object which you pass to `$.ajax`.

Comment: Okay, I changed jsoncallback to jsonp in the url and now it works, thank you for your help.