# ajax calling jsonp randomly success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I tried to create a cross domain test to get data from different page. All the pages are using the same jsonp.

```
m1({"appNo":"7","user":"carol","uid":"id001"})
```

and this is the ajax function:
url_6 is the list of url url_6[a.jsp,b.jsp,c.jsp....]

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$.each(url_6, function(index,appPage) {
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',    
          url: appPage,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          crossDomain: true,          
          cache:false,
           jsonp:"callback", 
           jsonpCallback: 'm1',
          success: function(data){  
                    uid1=data.uid;
                    APPList1.push(new DataObj(title1,uid1));
                    },
          error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
                                    }
        });
   });
```

});

I have 5 pages contained the same jsonp, sometime 1,3,5 work and 2, 4 got parse error (but chrome console network showed that the js files were return successfully 200 and the file is containing data. 
when I refresh the page, 1,2,3 got success and 4,5 got error.

the callback url is sth like `https://www.otherdomains/xxx.jsp?callback=m1&_=1410160716447`

I have tried to remove "m1" in both ajax function and jsonp and use "callback" instead, but all request got error message.

Whats going on?

[Why do a random number of these JSONP requests fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477982/why-do-a-random-number-of-these-jsonp-requests-fail)  is quite similar to my problem, but I am not that sure...

this is the jsonp created in jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
String str = "{\"appNo\":\"" + "1" + 
                                "\",\"user\":\"" + user + 
                                "\",\"uid\":\"" + uid +  "\"}";

String json = "ml(" + str + ")";

response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Comment: If you specify a callback function, you have to define the function, and it has to be a global function. If you want jQuery to handle this for you automatically, don't specify the callback, like it says in that other question.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Barmar,one error message -"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" is fixed, but the random success problem is still occur and the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: ml is not defined" is still here.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ml is not defined app1_backstage.jsp?callback=m1&_=1410165368232:1
(anonymous function) this error message is for app1, but parse error are still sometime occur randomly among app2-5

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the problem.

Because after ajax requested jsonp response, it will create a callback function. In my case, it is call 'm1'. However, because all of my jsonp response is :

```
m1({"appNo":"7","user":"carol","uid":"id001"})
```

hence, they are using the same callback function is javascript. 
I got 200 OK in the request, but after the jsonp response came back, the m1 function was using by the other m1 callback. So, some jsonp response do not have callback function to use.

The problem gone when I modified the jsonp name in jsp to be m1, m2, m3....and also changed in ajax function.

However, I would like to try to use the callback function automatically generated by ajax....